# Assigning mountpoints per USB port

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mount, mount-point

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspbian Jessie Lite. I have a Zero4U 4 port USB hub (it's permanently attached) I'm looking to assign a mountpoint to each USB port, so that any drive plugged into port 1 will always use the mountpoint /media/backup for example. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

First, plug in a drive to the port you want to map a mountpoint to. Use `sudo blkid` to get the /dev/sd** path to the drive & note this down/remember it. I'll be using '/dev/sda1'

Second, use `udevadm info --name=/dev/sda1 | grep disk/by-path`, which should give you a readout something like:

```
S: disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Switch_4C530001110415101044-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP_1 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/5936-F7EA
```

It's the `platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1` that we want. It might look fairly different depending on your device & hub. Copy it/note it down then open up fstab config `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and on a new line:

```
/dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /media/card exfat auto,nofail,noatime,users,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

replace `/media/card` with the mountpoint you desire, and make sure the bit following `/dev/disk/by-path/` matches what you copied earlier. The other options are variable depending on what you want.

Ctrl-X, Y, enter, to save fstab, then reboot and you should now have an auto-mounting usb port! You can repeat the previous steps for each port :)

Hope this helps anyone looking to do the same.